# CSS animation-delay doesn't work in reactJS with Chrome or Safari

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I have three images and some text blocks that I want to display in sequence so that they fade in but start the fade-in at different times.

I have read all the similar issues here but I have not found a solution as yet.

```
.imgCommunity3 {
  max-width: 12.5%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 50s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 50s;
  -o-animation-delay: 50s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 50s;
  animation-delay: 50s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 15s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 15s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 15s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 15s;
  animation: fadeIn 15s;
}
```

I have tried with the animation-delay before and after the fade-in block but it makes no difference.  All the blocks appear at the same time - the only difference is that they fade-in at different speeds.

It should be so simple!

I am running on a Mac with Chrome and Safari - it is the same on either browser.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine for me so could you put up a working snippet that we can run which demonstrates the problem. Only comment so far is that the unprefixed animation fadein setting should come after all the prefixed ones, but I doubt if that is the problem.

Comment: I moved th offending animation to the end - as you suggested, it made no difference.  What is the best way to provide you with a :snippet" ?  Stephen

Comment: @SunbeamRapier There is a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) tool to use. Include HTML (your rendered HTML, not your reactjs component) and the CSS.